# Using specific filename for React components and containers with Webpack

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack

I'd like to know how to rename my component and container typescript files from the generic `index.tsx` to something more specific like `mycomponent.tsx` to improve project navigation.

Currently the directory structure is as follows:

`app/
    containers/
        container1/
            index.tsx
            style.css
        container2/
            index.tsx
            style.css`

which I'd like to change to:

`app/
    containers/
        container1/
            container1.tsx
            style.css
        container2/
            container2.tsx
            style.css`

I've already tried a few things like naively renaming and renaming/importing into a `index.tsx`, but this always seems to break all my imports.

Comment: Have you tried keeping index.ts and putting `export * from "./container1";` inside it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it in the following way

```
app/
    containers/
        container1/
            index.ts
            container1.tsx
            style.css
        container2/
            index.ts
            container2.tsx
            style.css
```

and in every index.ts declare all of the exports. Think about it as about an interface to your component API. The simplest version can contain only export for the component itself.

```
export { default } from "./Container1";
```

Comment: you copied my answer :/

Answer (score 1):

So we had a very similiar situation what we've moved to is like this

```
app/
    containers/
        container1/
            container1.jsx
            index.jsx
            style.css
```

the index.jsx then looks something like this

```
import Container1 from './Container1 '
export default Container1
```

Then when we need to import its just

```
import Container1 from 'containers/Container1'
```

We use redux-cli with blueprints to do a lot of our boilerplate code, so this pattern is build into our components and containers. It also makes it easier for navigation to